# os.path.exists() return False for filename with directory path which is created by ln(Ubuntu)

Tags: python-3.x, os.path

I have one filename with directory name which is solflink to another directory. os.path.exists(file) return False.

What's the right way to check if file exists?

Answer (score 0):

If the directory structure looks like this:

```
.
├── bar -> ./foo/
└── foo
    └── test.txt
```

`os.path.exists` returns `True`, as expected.

```
import os
print(os.path.exists('./bar/test.txt'))

# True
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are confirming a directory's exist, not file. I think `subprocess` module can help you.

```js
import subprocess

command = 'ls {}'.format(your_path)
print(subprocess.call(command, shell=True))
```

This will run `ls` command on linux and get [returncode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen.returncode), if returncode is 0 means run command sucessfully which means your ln file exist.